# Selenium element visible listener

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my testing application error and successful messages will be visible in element which has 5-10 second timeout. That element only will be shown in the event of error and successful messages. It is not a pop-up message. I wrote a method to take screenshot in the event of failure. But in that screenshots error is not visible because of it's timeout. 
I will appreciate you if you can give me any idea about how to implement a listener to catch the visibility of the error element. I can write findelement after every submit command. But I think it's not practical.

Comment: I need a listener which invokes at the presence of such element. Put a method to catch error message after every action is not practical

Answer (score 1):

You can even use FluentWait like this -

```
public Boolean fluentWait(WebDriver driver, final By awaitedElement) {
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    Boolean flag = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed();
        }
    });

    return flag;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I need a listener which invokes at the presence of such element. Put a method to catch error message after every action is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebDriverWait` like

```
/**
 * Method to wait until element is visible
 * @param driver WebDriver instance
 * @param identifier identifiers used to select element
 * @param timeout Timeout duration
 * @return Element
 */
public WebElement waitUntilElementIsVisible(By identifier, long timeout) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(identifier));
    return element;
}
```